# Send calendar event invitations on behalf of a user with Microsoft Graph

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have a web app that allows receptionists to create calendar events on Outlook/Office365. To manage the events I use Microsoft Graph. The app sends the Graph requests under his own identity, because I need it to have no user interaction for logging in, so it uses Client_ID and Client_Secret with administrator rights to do everything. I can create events on the calendars of any user in the organization, which kinda works like creating an event "On behalf of", but there's a problem. When you create an event in someone else's calendar, Outlook will send the invitations as the calendar's owner, and this means that if the owner doesn't have permission to send messages to a mailbox (for example, a room mailbox), the invitation will never arrive. I need it to send the invitations from another user account (the receptionist that creates the event), like Office 365 does when you create an event on a shared calendar. Is that possible? Or is there any workaround to accomplish what I need?

Comment: Are you using app-only authentication then and not delegated authentication? if that is the case there is NO user context at all.And therefore the calendar isn't truly shared with a user, the way the shared calendar is being accessed is via Read.All admin consent and the send mail process if via non user app-only flow. That is why you are hitting this. If you used delegated authentication this would work correctly.

Comment: Is there a way to implement delegated authentication without asking the current user for credentials? I mean, using only the admin consent of the app.

Comment: No. You would require the user to consent to use a token on behalf of them. I think what you're asking for is app-only ability to do this right?